# dir_ls - how to make "glob" case insensitive

Tags: r, tidyverse

library(fs)

**`dir_ls(glob = "*.R)`**  lists all the `.R` files in the directory

However, **`dir_ls(glob = "*.r")`**  does not return anything
How do I make `glob` become case insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `...` argument in `fs::dir_ls()` to pass `ignore.case` to `grep()`:

```
dir_ls(glob = "*.r", ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `glob2rx` to convert the glob to a regular expression and then use `list.files` with the `ignore.case=TRUE` argument:

```
list.files(pattern = glob2rx("*.R"), ignore.case = TRUE)
```